Для чего может понадобится обнуление значимого типа?
int? Value = null;
null же для ссылочных типов, и ссылочные типы по умолчанию равны null, значимые равны 0;
Тогда в каком случае может понадобится присвоение значимому типу null?

Вы перепутали int и int?.

Как это можно использовать:0 — это заданное значение, null — не заданное, никак иначе обозначить не заданное значение не получится, какое для этого выбрать значение кроме null.

Вот пуля пролетела и ага...

Например для совместимости с некоторыми структурами данных в JSON при сериализации/десериализации.
Представьте, что сервер может прислать такой JSON ответ
{
  "value": 0
}

А может такой
{
  "value": null
}

Или вообще такой
{
}

Как отличить, 0 пришёл или ничего? Без использования nullable типа никак. Точнее это было бы сильно сложнее.
public class Model
{
    public int? Value { get; set; }
}

А так, зависит от потребностей. Это всего-лишь ещё группа типов в копилку к существующим.

для приведенного примера с тремя вариантами nullable типы ничем не помогут: ты не сможешь отличить {   "value": null } от { }

@Grundy Почему не сможешь? Сможешь. Ридер позаботится о требовании к наличию поля в жсон. Остается просто прочитать значение.

@Grundy допустим, а проблема ли это?

@Grundy ======/

В жизни часто бывают случаи, когда данных нет или они недостоверные. В таких случаях можно использовать null.
Если в такой ситуации использовать 0, то это уже совершенно определённое количество.
Для работы с такими данными предусмотрен тип "Nullable<T>":
int? Value = null;
if (Value.HasValue) ...

Широкое применение такие типы находят при работе с базами данных, в которых есть возможность объявлять любое поле nullable. Такие поля как раз и описываются nullable-типами.
